# Multiple user stream 1 video (Bandwidth calculation)

Tags: web-services, video-streaming, bandwidth

I have upload `.mp4` file on my server. The video file size is 58 MB. I have some question:

- If 10 users stream this video at the same time then how much bandwidth they are used?
- If video consuming too much bandwidth then what is alternative way?

I have not too much bandwidth.

Comment: whats your streamer type?

Comment: my website is not a streaming sites. this video is like a screen cast (how to use this site) and i add this video on home screen

Comment: Aha ok, then the usage bandwidth is something like download a video file, for 10 user =10*sizeOfVideoFile

Comment: @combo_ci thats mean if 10 users watch this video at the same time then (58*10=580 MB) used?

Comment: alternative way is you use some Streamer Technique line `HLS` to to find target device or decrease the video size while streaming

Comment: if they see all of video file,_58*10=580 MB_ is correct..if leave the video in middle of a video, then _58/2 MB_

Comment: To save bandwidth in your server, you can host your video in a CDN, (Edgecast, Akamai,...) Some players like Flowplayer offer you hosting service directly. But you need to pay for that,

Answer (score 1):

The usage bandwidth is something like download a video file, for 10 user `bandwidth =10*SizeOfVideoFile`. If a user see all of video file and file size is for example `58`, `58*10=580 MB` of bandwidth used..if the user leave the video in middle of a video, then use `58/2 MB`.

About *Alternative way*, you may use some Streamer Technique line [HLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) to to find target device *or* decrease the video size while streaming with for example [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/). You could also use `ffmpeg` for generate HLS stream.